# ROR : Assigning a method's variable from another method without passing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, parameters

I have a method, say

```
def method1
  method2
end
```

which will call another method, say

```
def method2
  @variable
end
```

How can I assign a value to this @variable from method1 without passing any parameters? IS it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid passing params?

Comment: The method is kinda generic and its being called from many other methods. So if I change it, it will have its own impact. Hope you got me.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's an instance variable, yes, it's possible:

```
class Foo
  def method1
    b = Baz.new
    b.variable = 'bar'
    b.method2
  end
end

class Baz
  attr_accessor :variable

  def method2
    @variable
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.method1 # => "bar"
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But thats not my case here. Say method1 and method2 belong to different classes. Apart from that, variable has its own value in the class where method1 is present. I cant manipulate the value of @variable here.

Comment: The `attr_accessor` here is a bit redundant

Comment: @ArvinthShriram, please write a better question then. Give clear examples of what you are trying to do. How am I supposed to guess that?

Comment: @ArvinthShriram, I edited my answer for the case where you have to classes. I'm still not sure what you are trying to do exactly though.